# How to Get UTC time zone in Jmeter

Tags: java, performance, testing, time, jmeter

We have to Export and Download the PDF file from the application. The File name contains Filename, Date and Time(UTC).

*1.Faculty report generated on 2019-01-17 13:28:01 PM by Test,User1.zip*

so we are trying to capture the time but we are getting in IST zone. Could any one help us to get UTC Time ZONE on *JMETER*.

Comment: `13:28:01 PM`, is that redundant or what? I’m more used to either `13:28:01` alone or `01:28:01 PM`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Change your machine time to UTC , in that case JMeter automatically prints UTC time

Soluction 2: You can use [Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler)/ [JSR223 sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to change IST to UTC

The following code snippet can be used to convert time to different time zones

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
log.info("*******"+dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) ));
```

[image]

For more info on beanshell please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/testing-complex-logic-with-jmeter-beanshell/)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.